# Imagemagick batch converting memory overload

Tags: batch-file, cmd, imagemagick

I must to convert about billion of images from jp2 to jpg...

I create such .bat

```
for /d %%d in (*) do (
  for %%f in ("%%~d\*.jp2") do (
    convert -limit memory 0 -limit map 0 "%%~ff" -quality 25 "%%~dpf\jpg\%%~nf.jpg"
  )
)
```

but when it convert's over ~ 100 000 windows throw's me error's with free memory etc...  How can i do that memory is used more humanity? So that imageconverter? if yes then release that memory....  Maybe there are ways to thread this ot something else?

Now i get in concolse free memory error's and also window's throw erro's too...

Also if i delete limit memory 0 -limit map 0  i have the same problem...

Comment: I wonder whether launching `convert` in a separate space would help?  Try `start "" convert` etc. and see whether that makes a difference.

Comment: @rojo you better give example...

Comment: Well, what I had in mind was what you have above, but just put `start ""` in front of `convert -limit memory 0 -limit map 0` etc. so it looks like `start "" convert -limit memory 0 -limit map` and so on.  This is just a guess and I'm not sure whether it'll work, so I don't want to post it as a formal answer below.

Comment: @rojo i'w tried also:START /WAIT convert -limit memory 0 -limit map 0 "%%~ff" -quality 25 "%%~dpf\jpg\%%~nf.jpg"   but i see only cmd window instances are growing up with the speed of light

Comment: Do you still get the free memory errors when you do `start /wait convert -limit` etc?

Comment: @rojo i can't say it now)

Comment: @rojo i set up it for working in nigth.... in the morning will now))))

Comment: @rojo also i see for every loop item that new cmd windows of imagemagick is opened..... how to hide it? just to see cmd with loop?

Comment: @rojo i tried something like START /WAIT /NOCONSOLE convert -limit memory 0 -limit map 0 "%%~ff" -quality 23 "%%~dpf\jpg\%%~nf.jpg"  but error's...

Comment: Ah, I thought the window would disappear when `convert` completed.  Try `start /wait /b convert -limit memory 0` etc.  If that doesn't work, then you can try `wmic process call create` as an alternative to `start`.  I'll explain further if needed.

Comment: @rojo hm( with start /wait /b convert i get many convert.exe processes in taskmanager

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25307/discussion-between-rojo-and-brabertaser1992)

Comment: Please update the question with the actual error message(s) you get. Without this information anyone would be blindly guessing at the problem.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers did you see windows throw's me error's with free memory etc.... system is down.... i can't see anything! also rojo help's me....

Comment: So the system crashes? Are you running this as an administrator or as a restricted user? Did you try to actually *limit* memory usage (e.g. `-limit memory 64 -limit map 128`)? Have you run a [memory test](http://www.memtest.org/) to make sure it's not a hardware problem?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers  yes both! not hardware! but code... some edit's you can see in chat

Comment: @rojo now in taskmng i see that cmd process is loading system....   could encrease to 20mb per minute...

Comment: @rojo - all is ok, post it as an answer

Comment: also @rojo how to write checking, and not in loop space that if jpg subfolder didn't exists, than create one....

Comment: `if not exist "jpg\" md jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per our [chat session](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25307/discussion-between-rojo-and-brabertaser1992), the solution is not to use ImageMagick's `convert` for the conversion.  [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) supports [command line switches](http://www.etcwiki.org/wiki/IrfanView_Command_Line_Options) for batch processing, and works well using wildcards both in source and destination arguments.  You'll also need the [jpeg2000 plugin](http://www.irfanview.com/plugins.htm) to convert from jp2.

```
for /d %%d in (*) do (
    pushd "%%d"
    if not exist "jpg\" md jpg
    "c:\Program Files (x86)\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" *.jp2 /convert=jpg\*.jpg /jpgq=25
    popd
)
```